# Como acessar métodos estáticos de uma classe incluídos no consign no NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, orientação-a-objetos, módulo-ecmascript

Ola.
Estou construindo uma aplicação com nodejs e preciso realizar a autenticação dos usuários ao cadastrar um novo usuário e ao logar na aplicação. Estou utilizando o consign para realizar o autoload dos meus scripts, como vocês podem conferir logo abaixo

```
consign().include('app/routes').then('app/models').then('app/controllers').into(app);
```

A minha classe para autenticação (AutenticacaoDAO.js) está dentro do diretório *models* e esta implementado da seguinte forma:

```
class AutenticacaoDAO {
    constructor() {
        this._instance;
    }
    static getStance() {
        if (!this._instance) {
            this._instance = new AutenticacaoDAO();
        }
        return this._instance;
    }
// Demais métodos
}
module.exports = function () {
    return AutenticacaoDAO;
}
```

Como vocês podem ver, a um método estático que gera um nova instancia. Quando tento acessar este método na minha rota aparece o seguinte erro:
*TypeError: Class constructor AutenticacaoDAO cannot be invoked without 'new'*

```
module.exports.home = function (application, req, res) {
    var auth = application.app.models.AutenticacaoDAO().getInstance();
}
```

O node acusa o erro que eu preciso de um *new* para invocar a classe, mas como estou acessando um método estático que me devolve a instancia, não a necessidade instaciar o objeto. Porem, este mesmo erro não ocorre quando acesso classe pelo *require*:

```
module.exports.home = function (application, req, res) {
    var auth = require('../models/AutenticacaoDAO')().getStance();
}
```

Gostaria de saber como acessar essa e método utilizando o consign (já que não quero alterar a estrutura do projeto). Já busquei em outros fóruns a resposta para o meu problema mas não encontrei a solução. Alguém poderia me ajudar? se eu poderia organizar o projeto de uma outra forma? Sou novo em node js e javaScript, então ainda me perco em alguns conceitos e qualquer ajuda será bem vinda.

Comment: Mas então se é um método `estático` a chamada não deveria ser assim **`application.app.models.AutenticacaoDAO.getInstance();`**?

Comment: Sim, pensei a mesma coisa. Fiz a chama do método como você falou, mas agora ocorre o seguinte erro: _TypeError: application.app.models.AutenticacaoDAO.getInstance is not a function_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está chamando uma função que não existe.
Conforme o comentário do @LeAndrade chame o método da seguinte forma:

```js
module.exports.home = function (application, req, res) {
  var auth = application.app.models.AutenticacaoDAO.getStance();
}
```